# How to display text through a mouse click on a Jframe file using JSON/GSON

Tags: java, json, netbeans, jframe, gson

I am trying to basically from a button click in the JFrame, show a result of the JSON file, however I'm stuck on initialising the button click to display the results in the text area. At the moment this opens the JFrame correctly and shows the results, however, in the console. (basically, what code would I use in the getResultsButtonActionPerformed) method on the JFrame form. Thanks!

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

class Children extends NewJFrame {

public ArrayList<Child> children;




@Override
public String toString() {

    StringBuilder B = new StringBuilder();

    B.append("Number of planets = " + children.size() + "\n");

    for (Child P : children) {

        B.append(P.toString() + "\n");
    }

    return B.toString();
}
}



class Child {

public String id;
public String name;
public float percentage;
    public float sampling_error;
    public int word_count;
    public String word_count_message;



// Constructor
public Child(String id, String name, float percentage, float sampling_error, int word_count, String word_count_message) {

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.percentage = percentage;
            this.sampling_error = sampling_error;
            this.word_count = word_count;
            this.word_count_message = word_count_message;

}


@Override
public String toString() {

    return "ID" + id + " : Name = " + name + "; Percentage = " + percentage + "; Sampling_Error = " + sampling_error + "; Word Count = " + word_count + "; Word Count Message = " + word_count_message;
}
}



public class Assignment {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // 1. New Gson processing instance
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    // 2. Create class hierarchy from the planets.json file.  To level class structure is the SolarSystem class.
    Child S = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("lol.json"), Child.class);

    // 3. Print class hierarchy to verify JSON loaded okay.
    System.out.println(S);

            NewJFrame form = new NewJFrame();
            form.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

And my JFrame code as I'm using netbeans

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}
private void getResultsButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 

 ;

}                                                

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

 /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton getResultsButton;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane result;
private javax.swing.JTextArea resultsText;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find attach a small example. You should replace

```
MyFrame.this.text.setText(...
```

by your code to get the JSON string.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();

    public MyFrame() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton but = new JButton("Go");
        add(but, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        but.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                SwingWorker work = new SwingWorker() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        MyFrame.this.text.setText("Hello @" + new Date());
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                work.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame f = new MyFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I'm a bit confused what goes in the NewJFrame.this.text.SetText  (what goes in the 'text' part as it's coming up udnerlined)

Comment: I wanted to keep it simple but complete. You really need only `text.setText(` here. The give example makes it explicit that `text` is a reference to the enclosing class from the  [nested inner anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).